# Why do adjacent rectangles create a banding effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, rectangles, visual-artifacts

I've created some rectangles using the following code:

```c#
double width = 6.546;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = i * 10,
        Fill = Brushes.Blue,
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, i * width);
    Canvas.SetBottom(rect, 0);

    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: verticalbanding]

There are vertical lines of varying lightness.  Why do they appear?  They can be avoided by using a large `width` value.  Is there any other way to avoid them?

Comment: Pixels are not floating point. They are integral. Try making your width an integer. You should not see them.

Comment: testing using `int width = 6;` yielded no bands

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Changing `width` changes the slope in the drawing, so it does not accomplish the original intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem here is that `Width = width` sets the rectangle width to 6, but `Canvas.SetLeft(rect, i * width)` sets the positions of the rectangles to 0, 6, 13, 19, 26,… (as integers obtained by truncating products of approximately 0, 6.546, 13.092, 19.638, 26.184,…). As you can see, some of the positions are 7 units apart, such as 6 and 13 or 19 and 26. Therefore, the six-unit rectangle does not span the seven-unit distance.

In this case, setting the width with `Width = ceil(width)` (which is 7) guarantees that the rectangles are wide enough to span the distances between them.

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115935/298225) suggests that you use `int` numbers, it is not clear that this is desirable. If you convert the calculations to `int`, you must either set the positions to multiples of one integer (6 or 7) or figure out a way to calculate the same positions (0, 6, 13, 19, 26,…) by using integer arithmetic instead of floating-point. The former is a choice to change the drawing to suit the arithmetic, which is undesirable. The latter preserves the slope in your drawing but has the same banding issue.

That answer also suggests using a floating-point version of the drawing objects. That is a reasonable approach. Note, however, that this merely reduces the rounding errors (from integer units to the finer floating-point units, at this magnitude); it does not eliminate them. In large drawings, there may still be an occasional drawing artifact unless you take care to avoid it. So understanding the details is important. Even with floating-point, you would want to ensure the width is set to be at least as large as any change in position.

Another option is to change the scale of the canvas, if your drawing interface supports that. If you can multiply the scale by 1000 (but keep the final drawing the same size), then your scale changes from 6.546 to 6546, and you can set the width to exactly 6546 instead of 6000 or 7000. As you can see, we are back to the key issue: You must set the width to a value at least as great as the difference between any two positions.

As stated previously, setting the width to 7 would make this drawing acceptable. The reason I discuss other solutions is that, in some drawings, changing the width from the ideal of 6.546 to 7 increases the size of the object undesirably. The other solutions improve upon that by allowing you to maintain a width closer to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, please add this line to the code (before adding `Rectangle`) to see how **easily** the problem goes away!

```
 canvas.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
```

Contrary to what mentioned by some answers including the first of mine, this issue **is not related to floating point numbers**, rather it is related to the rendering system used in `WPF` called *device-independent unit measurement* but this might cause artifacts in devices operating at greater than 96 dots per inch (dpi). Microsoft decleared the issue:

> ... this dpi independence can create irregular edge rendering due to anti-aliasing. These artifacts, commonly seen as blurry or "soft" edges, can occur when the location of an edge falls in the middle of a device pixel rather than between device pixels ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualxsnappingguidelines.aspx))

But the solution is also provided by `SnapToDevicePixels` property. (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx))

Comment: I don't think I can use RectangleF, as it's not a UIElement: "cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'" when adding it to a Canvas.

Comment: Yes, you're right I wasn't familiar with WPF, I'm gonna experiment some other methods to resolve the problem, I will post another answer later

Comment: @epalm See this new answer and enjoy!

Comment: Sorry but adding `SnapsToDevicePixels = true` still results in substantial visual artifacts on some of my data sets.

Comment: @epalm what other data? can you explain them?

Comment: Using ceil(width): http://i.imgur.com/agYbkpj.png
Using SnapsToDevicePixels: http://i.imgur.com/lchmjdv.png

Comment: @epalm I'm pretty sure that this issue must be addressed by this **Snapping** but there's another Property `Visual.VisualXSnappingGuidelines` ([MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualxsnappingguidelines.aspx)) that maybe should configured correctly to solve the problem. Current MSDN help doesn't provide details about this, I think you'd better to discuss this in [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/home). The professionals there probably know the trick.

Comment: SnapsToDevicePixels  rounds to the closest pixel, this could be larger or smaller if 1 rect rounds down and the next up, then you will still get the results the OP is complaining about, though with a solid 1 pixel gap not a fuzzy anti-aliasing one